# Fix 'error establishing a database connection' on website hosted at an EC2 instance

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have the website lmvjewelry.com which I'm hosting on an AWS EC2 instance with  WordPress and Open Litespeed technologies. I have everything connected on Route 53. I have issued an SSL on Amazon and attached it to a Load Balancer. Previously I was having issues with the site loading time. It would work fine for some time, and suddenly it wouldn't complete the loading process, and just throw an error 504 I guess. Don't remember if it was 504 or 505 something like that, after a failed attempt to loading. So I would go back to the console, reboot the instance, or stop it and start it again and that would fix the issue. But now it is showing this error with the database connection, so, I'm sure I might not be implementing the best practices here, and that's why I'm requiring assistance because I do not only want to solve the issue but also to learn the best practices to avoid this happening in the future.

Comment: are you using localhost as a DB host?

Comment: I really dont know. where can I see this?

Comment: in your wp-config.php of root folder

Comment: Yes, I already checked and it is using localhost. I access the hosting through ssh.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. 

I am using a pre configured Amazon Machine Image called ´WordPress with LiteSpeed Cache (Powered OpenLiteSpeed´. https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/LiteSpeed-Technologies-Inc-WordPress-with-LiteSpee/B07KSC2QQN

The database is included there, with Wordpress: 

Main Components:

OpenLiteSpeed
LiteSpeed Cache
WordPress
phpMyAdmin
LSPHP


The instance ID IS: i-09f6eac711eb946b7

any thoughts on what should I do in this case? 

Thanks a lot.